# perforce shelve examples

Tags: perforce, shelve, unshelve

I have codelines Foo v1 and Foo v2 checked out from the depot, where v2 was created
from v1 by a p4 integrate command. I have some changes to Foo v1 which 
are not checked in (I don't want them to be checked in) - but rather
I want them applied to Foo v2.

How do I do this using p4 shelve?

Answer (score 1):

This [blog](http://www.perforce.com/blog/100601/p4-move-f-what-its) from perforce suggests `p4 move -f` is the way to go. (Although you might have to revert the deletes) [p4 move manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.2/manuals/cmdref/move.html).

Answer (score 0):

The next release (out in beta soon) will let you directly unshelve to a different branch using a branch spec.